# Centre content vertically unless larger

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

At the moment I've got a small project on which is a responsive website (uses the Skeleton responsive grid) I'm using jQuery to centre the content vertically in the viewport.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){                  
 $(window).resize(function(){
  $('.container').css({
   position:'absolute',
   left: ($(window).width() 
     - $('.container').outerWidth())/2,
   top: ($(window).height() 
     - $('.container').outerHeight())/2
 });    
 });
 // To initially run the function:
 $(window).resize(); 
});
</script>
```

The problem is when the viewport becomes smaller than the outer width of container it still applies an absolute position.

Ideally,I need something that says

If the viewport is the same or smaller than the outer width of .container then don't apply any positioning, however if the viewport is larger than .container apply absolute positioning to centre it in the view port?.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved with Jquery, as im scratching my head ?.

EDIT >>>>>

Would something like this be right, im kind of clutching at straws here.....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
 $(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document

$(window).height();   // returns heightof browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document

var width = $(window).width(); 
var height = $(window).height(); 

   if ((width >= 1024  ) && (height>=768)) {
 $(window).resize(function(){
  $('.container').css({
  position:'absolute',
  left: ($(window).width() 
 - $('.container').outerWidth())/2,
 top: ($(window).height() 
 - $('.container').outerHeight())/2
 });    
 });
 // To initially run the function:
 $(window).resize(); 
}
else {
//do nothing
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using
`$(window).width(); // returns width of browser viewport`
or
`$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document`
should work in conjunction with `$('.container').width()`

`if (width comparison) apply_formatting`

Comment: I have added an edit which your recommendations, but im not sure if I have written it correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){                  
     $(window).resize(function(){
          // Here is the new part:
          if(($(window).width() > $('.container').outerWidth()) && ($(window).height() > $('.container').outerHeight()) ){
             $('.container').css({
                  position:'absolute',
                  left: ($(window).width() 
                     - $('.container').outerWidth())/2,
                  top: ($(window).height() 
                     - $('.container').outerHeight())/2
             });
          }else{
             $('.container').css({position:'relative'});
          }    

     });
     // To initially run the function:
     $(window).resize(); 
 });
</script>
```

Hope it helps. The idea is that when both width & height of the container is smaller than the window viewport the absolute positioning applies, otherwise the relative(normal) positioning will apply.